# How to active clicked tab and inactive default?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with the code below where no tab is clickable. I want to make a tab active when clicked and other inactive.

```
    <html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault()
        $(this).tab('show')
        })
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     ...
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="myTab">
       <li class="active"><a href="Home.aspx" data-toggle="tab">HOME</a></li>
       <li><a href="AboutUs.aspx" data-toggle="tab">ABOUT US</a></li>
       <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx" data-toggle="tab">CONTACT US</a></li>
       <li><a href="Searchjob.aspx" data-toggle="tab">SEARCH JOBS</a></li>
     </ul>     
     ...
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: have a look at my answer. hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');

     //removing active class from other selected/default tab
    $("#myTab .active").removeClass("active");

    //adding active class to current clicked tab
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

Here is **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rCzdC/)**

Comment: Its working in demo. Is your site online? if yes, give me a link to inspect problem. Or just check console if there is any error there.

Comment: Its not online. But when I remove data-toggle, tabs are clickable, but not active. Why?

Comment: Because the tabs are simply links... so of course they will be clickable, the data-toggle is used by the Bootstrap JS in order to activate tab content... so it is required.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul i mean whenever i add data-toggle line, tabs cannot be clicked.

Comment: You need to provide an example.. use JS fiddle.. the demo in this answer is working perfectly so simply inspect the differences?

Answer (score 0):

Use script as mentioned below :

```
$('#myTab li').click(function() {
    $('#myTab li').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    $(this).addClass('active');

})
```

Comment: Same as before. I think problem is data-toggle="tab" line. Whenever i add it tabs become unclickable.

Comment: can you provide JSFiddle ?

Comment: @SpiderCode, `each()` isn't required to remove class `active` from all li as you demostrated, from jQuery you can simply remove all classes in single statement like i shown `$("#myTab .active").removeClass("active");`